# 64 bit and 32 bit Python Modules

Tags: python, module

Will 64 bit Python Modules work with a 32 bit Python 3.6.3?

I am trying to make a keylogger and I need some modules, I have a 3.6.3 32 bit python and should I get 32 or 64 bit modules?

Comment: um, how are you getting these modules?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ or Source Forge

Comment: Why don't you try it and see for yourself? (I doubt it would work.)

Comment: If you are interested in complied binaries then almost certainly no. What libraries are you interested in specifically? Why aren't you using `pip` or, if you want stuff in the scipy-stack, perhaps anaconda/conda?

Comment: are you writing a spyware?

Comment: @georgexsh Effectivaly yes, but the tutorial I am following does not allow you to plant it.